# Volumes and Areas - optimisation

Tags: calculus

> I have enough silver to coat one metre squared of surface area - I plan to coat a sphere and a cube - find dimensions of solids if total volume is to be a maximum? A minimum? One of the solids may have zero volume. I know volume of sphere plus volume cube
>   $$V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 + a^3$$
>   and area sphere plus area cube
>   $$A=4\pi r^2+6a^2=1$$
>   and derivative of V
>   $$\frac{\delta{V}}{\delta{r}}+\frac{\delta{V}}{\delta{a}}=4\pi r^2+3a^2=0$$
>   but where to from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try solving the equation $4\pi r^2 + 6a^2 =1$ for $a$, then substitute that into the original expression for $V$. Then, since you'll have $V$ in terms of $r$ alone, you can take the derivative $\frac{dV}{dr}$ of that equation.